# Trying to write a function in an external php file to manage admin menu visibility

Tags: actions, admin-menu

I am loading my php file by putting this into my theme's functions.php:

```
require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/manage-menus.php';
alter_menu('my-user', 'plugins.php', false);
```

The code in manage-menus.php looks like this:

```
function alter_item ($user, $items, $action) {
    global $current_user, $menu;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    switch ($action) {
        case false:
            if ($current_user->user_login == $user) {
                remove_menu_page ($items);
            }
            break;

        case true:
            if ($current_user->user_login == $user) {
                //Do something else
            }
            break;
    }   
}

function alter_menu($user, $items, $action) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'alter_item' );
    alter_item( $user, $items, $action );           
}
```

I though when I use the admin_menu hook I should be on the safe side... but it tells me that:

```
Call to undefined function remove_menu_page() in ....
```

Any ideas?

---

PS
I tried an OOP approach, which gave me the same result:

manage-menus.php:

```
abstract class admin_menu_alterations {
    function hook_alter_menu(){
        echo 'executing hook';
        add_action( 'admin_menu',array( $this, 'alter_menu' ) );
    }
    public abstract function alter_menu($user, $items);
}

class hide_admin_menu_items extends admin_menu_alterations {
    public function alter_menu($user, $items) {
        $this->hook_alter_mennu();

        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();  

        echo $current_user->user_login;
        if ($current_user->user_login == $user) {
            remove_menu_page ($items_to_be_removed);
        }   
    }
}
```

functions.php:

```
$hide_menu_items = new hide_admin_menu_items();
$hide_menu_items->alter_menu("my-user", "plugins.php");
```

Comment: This is too complicated and I wanted to remove this and ask a simpler question. If possible it would be lovely if a moderator could delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Михаил Семёнов is right, but I had to get another push by cybmeta in another thread, which lead to this:

functions.php:

```
$menu_alterations   = array(
    'user'          => array('my-userA', 'my-userB'),
    'items'         => array('plugins.php', 'options-general.php'),
    'action'        => false,
);  

include get_template_directory() . '/inc/manage-menus.php';
```

/inc/manage-menus.php:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() use ($menu_alterations) {
    global $current_user, $menu;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    foreach ($menu_alterations['user'] as $user) {
        switch ($menu_alterations['action']) {
            case false:
                if ($current_user->user_login == $user) {
                    foreach ($menu_alterations['items'] as $item) {
                        remove_menu_page ($item);
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's becouse you'r calling alter_item function outside action `admin_menu`

here's working example i just made, try to figure what's wrong with your's by your self, if you fail i'll explain

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'alter_items' );
function alter_items() {
    global $current_user, $menu;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $scopes = apply_filters( 'alter_items', array() );
    if( ! empty( $scopes ) ) {
        foreach( $scopes as $scope ) {
            switch ($scope['action']) {
                case false:
                    if ($current_user->user_login == $scope['user']) {
                        remove_menu_page( $scope['items'] );
                    }
                    break;

                case true:
                    if ($current_user->user_login == $scope['user']) {
                        //Do something else
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
function alter_menu($user, $items, $action) {
    add_filter( 'alter_items', function( $scope ) use( $user, $items, $action ) {
        //echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $user, $items, $action ); echo '</pre>';
        $scope[] = array(
            'user' => $user,
            'items' => $items,
            'action' => $action
        );
        return $scope;
    } );
}

alter_menu('admin', 'plugins.php', false);
```

PS: note that you need PHP 5.3.0 minimum

Comment: This seems to work, but seems very complicated. The above procedure is described in the wordpress codex and I am sure there must be an easier way.

Comment: You might skip `add_filter` in `alter_menu` and use `add_action( 'admin_menu', function() use( $user, $items, $action )...`. The thing is that in your examples you'r dubble calling a function `alter_menu` first time when u parse args and seccond is when the action is heppening.. So in action you don't have variables wich you write to `alter_menu` function.. As an enothere way you can create global variable and write your parsing variables to global and in action read them, but then, if you call your function later then action it woun't work.. do u undestand?